# Multiple spreadsheets imported into one using IMPORTRANGE

Tags: google-sheets-api, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query, importrange

I am trying to combine multiple spreadsheets into one master spreadsheet by using IMPORTRANGE. Tried the following:

```
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("187znjFwW25ZNSovWcAv43hjYynmsEJW_MU46BgoACZY","Status!A:BJ");IMPORTRANGE("2v4XB81Io7H70WBgmEu_gZ4233E7qf9l2Nfvlc1AfLuM","Status!A:BJ")},"where Col1 is not null")
```

or

```
={IMPORTRANGE("187znjFwW25ZNSovWcAv43hjYynmsEJW_MU46BgoACZY","Status!A:BJ");IMPORTRANGE("2v4XB81Io7H70WBgmEu_gZ4233E7qf9l2Nfvlc1AfLuM","Status!A:BJ")}
```

and always saw:

> In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows

I also made to sure to do IMPORTRANGE for each spreadsheet and click on 'allow' - so individually they are being imported but I cannot combine them into one sheet in the new spreadsheet.

Any thoughts?

Comment: just tried, nothing new happened.

Comment: unfortunately they dont hence me posting here :(

Comment: tried it but i don't think it worked, can you share an example of what you meant ? (to ensure I am putting the right syntax)-- thanks again pnuts! :)

Comment: Heya-- thanks again pnuts-- I tried that and it didn't work. The only thing that worked was putting a lot less columns :(

Answer (score 0):

Ensure dat the array is define to the actual source, eg.
=QUERY({IMPORTRANGE("187znjFwW25ZNSovWcAv43hjYynmsEJW_MU46BgoACZY","Status!A1:BJ1000");IMPORTRANGE("2v4XB81Io7H70WBgmEu_gZ4233E7qf9l2Nfvlc1AfLuM","Status!A1:BJ880")},"where Col1 is not null")

The Array on both import range needs to match exact total rows in the extract sheet.